# Compiler doesn't complain when an Array is assigned to a variable of type Any

Tags: arrays, swift, any

Consider the following code:

```
 var fruits : Any = ["apple", "mango",1]

 print(fruits)
```

The above code runs successfully.

Shouldn't the compiler complain that the type is not **[Any]** like it does for every other type?

Sorry, I am fairly new to this. Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: `Any` is the protocol to which all types conform, even arrays.

Comment: Thanks Martin! So by that logic, [Any] would never be required in any scenario? Since Any protocol conforms to arrays.

Comment: @Asha not related to your question but you should avoid using `Any` in most scenarios

Comment: Thanks Leo! I just wanted to get my basics strong.

Comment: @Asha: That is not correct. With `[Any]` you restrict to a type which is an array, without restricting the element type.

Comment: Okay, Now I understand! Thanks a lot Martin.